# How to choose my Theme in Android Studio layout preview

Tags: android, android-studio, android-theme

In my project's `res/values` directory, I have a `my_themes.xml` file that specifies custom attributes and two custom themes (light and dark). These themes get applied (in code) to [`Presentation`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Presentation) objects by way of [the third constructor parameter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Presentation#Presentation(android.content.Context,%20android.view.Display,%20int)).

I would like to be able to choose either of my two themes when I am editing my layout files, and see the themed results in the layout preview. When I run the code, everything works fine; this is just a question about how to get the layout preview to show me my theme.

It does not seem possible to choose my custom themes, however. When I click the dropdown to select the theme to use, only my "default" `AppTheme` (and its parents) are visible:

[image]

If I click into "More themes...", my custom themes are not among the options. Here I am searching for "My" (they are `MyLightTheme` and `MyDarkTheme`), but I get zero results:

[image]

---

my_themes.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <attr name="MyCustomAttr" format="reference"/>
    <attr name="MySecondCustomAttr" format="reference"/>

    <style name="MyLightTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen">
        <item name="MyCustomAttr">@drawable/light_thing</item>
        <item name="MySecondCustomAttr">@drawable/second_light_thing</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyDarkTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen">
        <item name="MyCustomAttr">@drawable/dark_thing</item>
        <item name="MySecondCustomAttr">@drawable/second_dark_thing</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Themed `Presentation` subclass:

```
open class MyThemedPresentation(outerContext: Context?, display: Display?, isLight: Boolean)
        : Presentation(outerContext, display, getTheme(isLight)) {

    companion object {

        @StyleRes
        @JvmStatic
        fun getTheme(isLight: Boolean): Int =
            when (isLight) {
                true -> R.style.MyLightTheme
                false -> R.style.MyDarkTheme
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: are your themes declared in the same module? typically they appeared if the current module sees them. if they're declared in a different module, and your module has no dependency to that module, then they won't be seen (unfortunately)

Comment: @cjurjiu yeah, they're all in the same module (the simple demo is only a single module). It feels like Android Studio only adds styles that are listed as themes in the manifest or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

I have been unable to figure out a way to get my themes to appear in the dropdown menu mentioned in my question, but I was able to work around the issue by adding the `tools:theme` attribute to the root view of the layout.

For example:

```
tools:theme="@style/MyLightTheme"
```

Then, regardless of what theme is selected in the dropdown, the layout preview will use the specified theme.

Comment: For me, I just needed to switch the qualifier, NOT theme. There's a "night theme" submenu under the rotation icon which lets you change it to night theme.